# Which Selenium method or command can be used to click on the following buttons?

Tags: python, selenium

Which method in Selenium with python can be used to click on the following buttons?

Button nr. 1:

```
<a href="/help.html"> = $0
<i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i> HELP </a>
```

Button nr.2:

```
<a class="active-menu-item" href="/help/making_service_requests.html">Service Requests</a>
```

Button nr.3:

```
<a href="/help/making_service_requests/transferring_service.html">Transfer Service</a>
```

I have already tried but wont work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="topmenuheader"]/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Transfer Service").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn").click()
```

I have encountered many instances where there are no id, no class etc, butand href available or an href with an html reference as mentioned above. These seem to be tricky as i have tried quite a few things. Maybe some of you have encountered these and could help out. Thanks

Comment: The second one looks correct but it returns a list so you need to click the first element in the list: `driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Transfer Service")[0].click()`

Comment: doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

These should work for those 3 elements. I showed multiple ways of getting those a tags either by href, class or text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[@href='/help.html']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[@class='active-menu-item']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[text()='Transfer Service']").click()
```

Comment: also not responding. throwing error _italic_aise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: _italic_

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath("path here")
Driver.click()
```

Comment: as you can see i already tried this simple approach. not working.